# Fallo con archivo.readlines()

Tags: python

Al usar el método de `readlines()`, me devuelve una lista vacía, sin embargo, sí me lee el texto. Si alguien me pudiera decir cual puede ser el fallo le estaría muy agradecido, porque yo no lo encuentro.

```
from io import open
from pyreadline import Readline


archivo_text=open("C:\\Users\\JuanF\\Desktop\\TFG\\texto_prueba.txt", "r")

text = archivo_text.read()

lineas = archivo_text.readlines()

archivo_text.close()

print(text)
print(lineas)
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué versión de Python estás utilizando? [Aquí](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/issues/65) encontré el reporte de errores a partir de la versión 3.9

Comment: Utilizo la versión 3.9.10, he tenido que instalar manualmente pyreadline en mi Windows. Todavía no he encontrado como solucionar esto pero muchas gracias por el enlace.

Comment: Readlines es la peor opción del mundo mundial. Revisa la respuesta que te ofrecen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción

```
texto = archivo_text.read()
```

lee todo el archivo de una. Por tanto, luego de ejecutada no queda nada por leer.

> Para leer el contenido de una archivo utiliza f.read(size), el cual
> lee alguna cantidad de datos y los retorna como una cadena de (en modo
> texto) o un objeto de bytes (en modo binario). size es un argumento
> numérico opcional. Cuando se omite size o es negativo, el contenido
> entero del archivo será leído y retornado; es tu problema si el
> archivo es el doble de grande que la memoria de tu máquina. De otra
> manera, como máximo size caracteres (en modo texto) o size bytes (en
> modo binario) son leídos y retornados. Si se alcanzó el fin del
> archivo, f.read() retornará una cadena vacía ('').

**Solución**

Elimina la instrucción.